# How to fetch stripe secret key and publish key from database in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I am trying to implement Stripe on a project in such a way the Sripe **secret key** and **publish key** will be **dynamic** and will be **fetched from the database**!

Comment: can you please show us your code, what you have tried so far to achieve this result?

Comment: I am using laravel cashier

below is from config/cashier.php
<?php

return [
    'key' => env('STRIPE_KEY'),

    'secret' => env('STRIPE_SECRET'),

];

so I need to fetch the stripe secret from database instead of fetching from from environment file.

Answer (score 0):

I think is not secure to store your Stripe Key and secret in plain text on a table, i assume that you also shoudn't encrypt it because it will not work properly on your app, but if you want it and you don't care about security, just create a new Migration ([Creating Migrations](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations)) with a table that can store your keys, for example:

```
// run command: php artisan make:migration create_stripe_keys_table

// Then in your new migration, just configure your table, example:

Schema::create('stripe_keys', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->increments('stripe_key');
    $table->increments('stripe_secret');
})
```

Now run php artisan migrate and your table will be ready.

Then just create a new model ([Laravel: Defining Models](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#defining-models)), call it for example `StripeKeys`, and configure it to use your table and finally in your code you just have to return the key you want:

```
<?php return [ 'key' => StripeKeys::find(/* the key you want */)->stripe_key, 'secret' => StripeKeys::find(/* the secret you want */)->stripe_secret, ];
```

I hope this can help you.